# Problem with \xymatrix in svjour3

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I attempt to compile the following

```
\newcommand{\arb}[1]{\ar@<-.15ex>[#1]\ar@<.15ex>[#1]\ar@<-.075ex>[#1]\ar@<.075ex>[#1]\ar[#1]}
\[\xymatrix{
& \arb{rr}^<<<<{}="1"^g & & \arb{dr}_<<<<{}="5"^f &\\
\arb{ur}^h \ar[rr]^>>>>>>{}="2"_>>>>>>{}="3"^k \arb{dr}_c &\ar[ur]^d\ar[dr]_e & &\\
& \arb{rr}^<<<<{}="4"_b & &\arb{ur}^<<<<{}="6"_a &
\ar@{=>}"1";"2"^{T}
\ar@{=>}"3";"4"^{V}
\ar@/_.6pc/@{=>}"5";"6"^{U}
}
\;\qquad
\xymatrix{
&\arb{rr}^>>>>>>{}="1"^g\ar[dr] & & \arb{dr}^f &\\
\arb{ur}_>>>>{}="5"^h \arb{dr}^>>>>{}="6"_c & &\ar[rr]^<<<<{}="2"_<<<<{}="3"& &\\
& \arb{rr}^>>>>>>{}="4"_b  \ar[ur]& &\arb{ur}_a &
\ar@{=>}"1";"2"^{A} 
\ar@{=>}"3";"4"^{C} 
\ar@/^.6pc/@{=>}"5";"6"^{B}}
\]
```

and I get the error

```
[2][3]<xymatrix
!Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
    $
l.157 }
```

When I hit "go to error" the space `\;\qquad` is highlighted. I'm using the header

```
\documentclass[draft]{svjour3}
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb} %amsxtra,amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage[v2,cmtip]{xy}
```

Please help. I'm trying to prepare the manuscript for submission. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) “Go to error” might be misleading. It's rather pointing on your first `xymatrix` usage (something in there is wrong). Why do you use `\input xy` _and_ `\usepackage{xy}`?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! The question about \input xy vs. \usepackage{xy} is interesting, though commenting out the latter doesn't affect the error message described above.

Comment: It has something to do with svjour3, but I don't know what.

Comment: That's odd. I've not gotten that error for this block.

Comment: Closed as too localized, as it was a hidden problem with the table of contents (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77973/xy-pic-trouble-with-svjour3).

Answer (score 2):

Processing your example (I don't have the `svjour3` class, so I used `article`) code one gets the error message

```
 ! Xy-pic error: in entry "1,4": No [dr] (is "2,5") from here.
 \xyerror@ ...#2}\fi \errmessage {Xy-pic error: #1}
```

which indicates the problem; on entry `1.4` you declared an arrow going down and to the right (to entry `2.5`), and no entry `2.5` exists. Adding an extra `&` character to the second row solves the problem :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb} %amsxtra,amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[all,v2,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\arb}[1]{\ar@<-.15ex>[#1]\ar@<.15ex>[#1]\ar@<-.075ex>[#1]\ar@<.075ex>[#1]\ar[#1]}
\[
\xymatrix{
& \arb{rr}^<<<<{}="1"^g & & \arb{dr}_<<<<{}="5"^f &\\
\arb{ur}^h \ar[rr]^>>>>>>{}="2"_>>>>>>{}="3"^k \arb{dr}_c 
   & &\ar[ur]^d\ar[dr]_e & & \\
& \arb{rr}^<<<<{}="4"_b & &\arb{ur}^<<<<{}="6"_a &
\ar@{=>}"1";"2"^{T}
\ar@{=>}"3";"4"^{V}
\ar@/_.6pc/@{=>}"5";"6"^{U}
}
\;\qquad
\xymatrix{
&\arb{rr}^>>>>>>{}="1"^g\ar[dr] & & \arb{dr}^f &\\
\arb{ur}_>>>>{}="5"^h \arb{dr}^>>>>{}="6"_c & &\ar[rr]^<<<<{}="2"_<<<<{}="3"& &\\
& \arb{rr}^>>>>>>{}="4"_b  \ar[ur]& &\arb{ur}_a &
\ar@{=>}"1";"2"^{A} 
\ar@{=>}"3";"4"^{C} 
\ar@/^.6pc/@{=>}"5";"6"^{B}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I copied that modified code into the original tex file and attempted to compile, and I got the same error I mentioned above. I'm not getting any error about a vacuous cell in the matrix, and it runs fine if I use article document class. The problem only originated when I attempted it in svjour3.

Comment: Actually the first time it compiles there are no problems, and then only on the second compile does it give that error.